# How do you fan out observables with reactive extensions

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a service that I would like to turn into a rx observable

The service has an interface of

```
    IEnumerable<Price> FetchUpdatedPrices()
    {
       //do work to return changed data since last update
    }
```

My idea was to use rx to allow a consumer to subscribe to updates. The implementation would  poll the service every x seconds and call the observer.

I came up with the following

```
    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<IEnumerable<Price>> observer)
    {

        IObservable<IEnumerable<Price>> updatedPrices = Observable.Interval(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1))
            .Select(r => FetchUpdatedPrices());

        return updatedPrices.Subscribe(observer);
    }
```

The problem is I would like the observer to see an `IObservable<Price>` rather than an `IObservable<IEnumerable<Price>>`

Could anyone give this Rx noob any pointers on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211809%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)?

```
IObservable<IEnumerable<Price>> updatedPrices = Observable.Interval(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1))
    .SelectMany(r => FetchUpdatedPrices());
```

Comment: Simple as that thank you, guess I was tired when looking at this :s

Comment: Should this not be `IObservable<Price> updatedPrices = Observable.Interval(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)).SelectMany(r => FetchUpdatedPrices().ToObservable());`?

Comment: Throw in a Multicast though, or every subscriber will get their own timer